# Can the Intel Curie modules be programmed in assembly using the Quark toolchain?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, intel, development-tools

I've been looking over an Intel Curie module for a project.

From the [datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/boardsandkits/curie/Intel_Curie_Module_Datasheet_V1.21.pdf) it looks like the Curie module contains an Intel Quark D1000 embedded processor along with a lot of other components. I'd like to use those components in my design.

From all of the documentation I can find, it looks like the Curie's toolchain only supports using a [higher level toolkit](https://iqsdk.intel.com/#/iqsdk) (which only seems to support their real-time Zephyr RTOS).

But the quark has a development environment called [Intel System Studio](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/8a/2b/issm-release-notes-u1-aug-2016.pdf) that supports using assembly, C, and can run on Linux and Windows.

If I use the Curie module will I still be able to do development at a low level using the Intel System Studio, upload code and debug it via JTAG tools, or will I not be able to do this?

I'm OK with writing my own stuff for the other modules in the Curie module module. I'm thinking that the higher level things just add some libraries and calling wrappers for those things. If that's the only issue I'm ok with that. I'm just wanting to know if anyone has experience with this and I'll be able to write using the Intel System Studio.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I came up with somewhat of an answer to my question.

First, Curie contains a Quark SE C1000 and not a D1000.

The higher level toolkit takes over a huge amount of [boot time setup of the processor](https://blog.hansenpartnership.com/anatomy-of-the-uefi-boot-sequence-on-the-intel-galileo/) (search for Quark), which would seem necessary when using what amounts to a CISC processor from more than 30 years ago as a MCU.

[Intel System Studio](https://blog.hansenpartnership.com/anatomy-of-the-uefi-boot-sequence-on-the-intel-galileo/) is usually used with the device, which supplies a C compiler and Arduino or a RTOS called Zephyr. Normally you are limited to C, but if you use an assembler that can produce the proper type of file (ELF) it can be linked with the toolchain.

One assembler that can be used is [flat assembler](http://flatassembler.net/).